# Конкатенация строк с помощью указателей

Tags: c, указатели

Является ли безопасной функция конкатенации, определенная следующим образом?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void concat(char *a, char *b) {
   while((*a) != '\0') a++;
   while((*b) != '\0') {
    *a = *b;
    a++;
    b++;
   }
   (*a) = '\0';
}

int main(void) {
  char a[] = "My name is";
  char b[] = " Catalisys";
  concat(a,b);
  char *read_a = a;
  while((*read_a) != '\0') { printf("%c",(*read_a)); read_a++; }
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: изменил концовку функции

Comment: Что такое "безопасной"??? Функция, работающая с указателями, в принципе не может быть безопасной в "среднестатистическом" понимании термина. О чем речь вообще?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Строки зашиты в код программы. Будет обрушение за счёт модификации запретной области памяти где находится прога. В конце функции забыл последний нуль добавить, будет ОЧЕНЬ длинная строка. Если под строку выделена динамическая память и её хватит на всю результирующую строку плюс один байт под ноль, то можно поюзать. В данном примере строки записаны в кучу, сначала обрушения не будет, но будет полная каша информации.

```
concat.s:
...
movabsq $2334392247088347469, %rax
movq    %rax, -32(%rbp)
movw    $29545, -24(%rbp)
movb    $0, -22(%rbp)
movabsq $8316297352736490272, %rax
movq    %rax, -48(%rbp)
movw    $29561, -40(%rbp)
movb    $0, -38(%rbp)
leaq    -48(%rbp), %rdx
leaq    -32(%rbp), %rax
movq    %rdx, %rsi
movq    %rax, %rdi
call    concat
...
```

Comment: "Будет обрушение за счёт модификации запретной области памяти где находится прога" - Нет, конечно. Никаких попыток модификации "строки зашитых в код программы" тут нет и близко.Тут есть обычный выход за пределы массива. "В данном примере строки записаны в кучу," - это что за чушь??? В какую еще кучу?

Comment: Куча это область памяти в виде стека для локальных переменных. Адрес этой памяти записан по адресу **%rbp**. Много цифр это коды букв, они записаны в эти кусочки памяти. Все локальные переменные записаны очень рядом и любые записи не по адресу портят значение этих переменных.

Comment: *Кучей* в русскоязычной терминологии традиционно назвается "heap", т.е. динамическая память. Если вы будете называть стек "кучей", вас не поймут.

Comment: Типичный уход за пределы массива `a`, притом умышленная :)

Answer (score 0):

Убрать переполнение буфера `a`, исправить на это:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void concat(char c[], const char a[], const char b[])
{
   char *aa = (char*)a, *bb = (char*)b, *cc = (char*)c;
   while((*aa) != '\0') { *cc++ = *aa++; }
   while((*bb) != '\0') { *cc++ = *bb++; }
   (*cc) = '\0';
}

int main(void) {
  const char a[] = "My name is";
  const char b[] = " TeaPot";
  char c[(sizeof(a) + sizeof(b) + 1)] = {0};
  concat(c,a,b);
  printf("%s\n", c);
  return 0;
}
```

писано с мобильного, возможны синтаксические ошибки, проверьте :)